# Normalizing an error payload in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Let's say I have a `Person` model

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend
  firstName: DS.attr 'string'
  lastName: DS.attr 'string'
  email: DS.attr 'string'
```

I'm using `ember-data`, calling out to a REST API that uses underscored attribute names (ie, `firstName` is `first_name`), so I'm customizing the `ApplicationSerializer` to perform "across the board" normalization (see the [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html)).

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend
  keyForAttribute: (attr) -> 
    Ember.String.underscore(attr)
```

This works great for both serializing and normalizing the data to and from the server. However, what about errors from the server?

Let's say I have an action that tries a `PUT` to update a `Person` record. So I have the button

```
# Somewhere in the person/edit template
<button {{action "save"}}>Save</button>
```

And the controller

```
App.PersonEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  actions:
    save: ->
      @get('model').save().then(@onDidCreate.bind(@)).fail(@onBecameError.bind(@))

  onBecameError: (res) ->
    @get('model').set 'errors', res.responseJSON.errors
```

But this sets errors on the underscored attribute names (ie, `{first_name: ["can't be blank"]}`). In order to show the errors, I would have to bind my view to the underscored attribute names. Then my view would be binding to both `firstName` and `first_name` attributes.

How can I normalize the error payload using the same serializer to maintain consistency?

---

**EDIT**

Instead of overriding the `ajaxError` hook, I ended up just using the `ActiveModelSerializer` and `ActiveModelAdapter` as kingpin2k mentioned in his answer. This will normalize and serialize data and errors from underscored attributes to camelCased attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override the ajaxError hook on your adapter, here's how the active model adapter does it.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
 /**
    The ActiveModelAdapter overrides the `ajaxError` method
    to return a DS.InvalidError for all 422 Unprocessable Entity
    responses.

    @method ajaxError
    @param jqXHR
    @returns error
  */
  ajaxError: function(jqXHR) {
    var error = this._super(jqXHR);

    if (jqXHR && jqXHR.status === 422) {
      var jsonErrors = Ember.$.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText)["errors"],
          errors = {};

      forEach(Ember.keys(jsonErrors), function(key) {
        errors[Ember.String.camelize(key)] = jsonErrors[key];
      });

      return new DS.InvalidError(errors);
    } else {
      return error;
    }
  }

});
```

yours might be similar, but ignore 422

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
 /**
    The ActiveModelAdapter overrides the `ajaxError` method
    to return a DS.InvalidError for all 422 Unprocessable Entity
    responses.

    @method ajaxError
    @param jqXHR
    @returns error
  */
  ajaxError: function(jqXHR) {
    var error = this._super(jqXHR);

    if (jqXHR) {
      var jsonErrors = Ember.$.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText)["errors"],
          errors = {};

      forEach(Ember.keys(jsonErrors), function(key) {
        errors[Ember.String.camelize(key)] = jsonErrors[key];
      });

      return new DS.InvalidError(errors);
    } else {
      return error;
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: I didn't even know there was an `ActiveModelSerializer`. Since I'm using Rails as a backend I'll try to use this adapter instead. How does it expect errors to come back from the server?

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/activemodel-adapter/lib/system/active_model_adapter.js

Comment: I'm pretty sure in the format you are sending them, it's DS.ActiveModelAdapter

Comment: Is it sending back a 422?  So the model is in an invalid state?

Comment: n/m, looks like that's what unprocessable_entity is

Comment: One sec, I'll setup an example to try it out

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the ActiveModelAdapter. Could it be the way I'm setting the errors on the model in the controller? (`@get('model').set 'errors', res.responseJSON.errors`)

Comment: oh, try getting it off the `res.errors` instead of from the responseJSON

Comment: There is no errors object on res :( I think this is the cause of the problem though.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I still can't figure out why it's setting errors using underscored attribute names.

Comment: Try overriding the ajaxerror hook and see if it's even hitting hit

Comment: Ha! I was using `ActiveModelSerializer` but not `ActiveModelAdapter`. I updated my `ApplicationAdapter` to use the `ActiveModelAdapter` and it worked. Thanks a lot!